# Jquery general tagName

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this possible to acces selector with a general tag name.
Like in sql if you want to find a varchar that contains "ert" you write it "%ert%"

can I go like `("#%_tagname%").hide();`?

Comment: The `#` at the start of the selector means it's an ID, which isn't what you seem to want.

Comment: The term "tag name" generally refers to, well, the **tag name** - like "div" or "input" or "img".  You seem to be asking about "id" attribute values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use starts with, ends with, and contains:

```
$('[id^="start_"]').... // the id starts with `start_`

$('[id$="_end"]').... // the id ends with `_end`

$('[id~="something"]').... // the id contains `something` within
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I haven't actually used this selector before. Your answer is far better so I just removed mine.

Answer (score 0):

There are selectors that can help you.

try:

```
$('[id*="tagname"]').hide();
```

source:
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this -

**HTML**

```
​<div id="yesno">hello</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**jQuery**

```
$("div[id*='yes']").hide();​
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$('*[id*="tagname"]')
```

That would select all items that have attribute id containing the tag name.

I just realised, it removed my initial comments because of the HTML formatting so it was missing the original *'s

Comment: This is completely **wrong**. you are basically just doing `$('#tagname')`

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't copied in the correct thing. It's:   $('*[id*="tagname"]')

Comment: Whoa. you definitely **do not** want to do that!

Comment: Why? You can then select anything on the page with a given tag value. You run $('*[id*="n"]') on this page and it will select every element that contains n in it's id.

Comment: You **do not** need that 1st star. it is implied.